# Using function inside of function, input occurs twice and once is desired

Tags: python, urllib

I'm trying to get input from the user once and then open those links. I tried fitting the first function inside of the second function, and it all works--but it asks me for the search item TWICE. I want this to happen once. How do I correct the logic?

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re 
from collections import Counter 
import string 
from string import punctuation
from collections import OrderedDict 
from bs4.element import Comment
import pandas as pd
import requests
import re
import numpy as np 

def user_input(): 
    brand = input("search item?")
    link1 = 'https://google.com/search?q='+brand+'&u=&'
    link2 = 'http://yahoo.com/?site=thedrive&q='+brand 
    link3 = 'https://www.bloomberg.com/'+brand+'/news/'
    link4 = 'https://www.cnet.com/roadshow/make/'+brand+'/'
    list1 = [link1,link2,link3,link4]
    return list1 

def request(): 
    html_list = [] 
    list1 = user_input() 
    for item in list1: 
        with urllib.request.urlopen(item) as response:
            html = response.read()
            html_list.append(html)
    return len(html_list) 

user_input()  
request()
```

Comment: Mark as correct?

Answer (score 1):

You are calling user_input() twice. Remove the call in your second to last line of code and you should be good.